# htaccess redirect from www to normal domain except one folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need have redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com all calls except one folder "/service/*". For example

```
http://www.domain.com/ => http://domain.com/
http://www.domain.com/users/* => http://domain.com/users/*
http://www.domain.com/service/* => http://www.domain.com/service/*
```

I cannot write correct .htaccess rule.

My current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Then post your attempt so far so that we can help fix it.

Comment: Do you already some .htaccess rules? If yes then post them in your question.

Comment: Added my current htaccess file